# How to reset some packages in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, gtk

I was trying to install [gnome-photos](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Photos) on my ubuntu 14.04

As a dependency package I installed gtk+-3.0 on my ubuntu
(It is not available through synaptic or through default repos so I downloaded source code
and installed it alongwith its own dependencies)

I think while installing gtk+-3.0 it replaced my original gtk installations and now all my UI elements have changed.

Mainly the toolbars and windows in applications like emacs, synaptic have changed completely but icons are still same!(Also nautilus is working properly!)

Here are some screenshots:

Synaptic:
[image]

settings:
[image]

I don't want this layout I want to revert back!

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: 1. Change theme using Unity tweak tool to see if with other theme it works 2. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk3-engines-unico` if it doesn't work try 3. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should reinstall GTK 3.10 as that is the default GTK package in Ubuntu 14.04. Hopefully, that overwrites your custom installation and fixes your UI problem.

Unfortunately, that seems like it will break your Gnome-Photos app unless you find out a way to install GTK 3.0 for just that app. (I don't know if that's possible)